# Instantiating a variable in a mathematical expression

Tags: c++, string, postfix-notation, infix-notation

I am trying to code a C++ app that will be able to calculate a mathematical expression. Doing so I must convert a infix expression into a postfix expression and then calculate the value.

Before I can start with the conversion of the infix expression into a postfix expression and to calculate it I must first instantiate the x and y by giving it values. My question is this. How can I search for x and y in the 'expr' string in the `instantiateVariable` function and assign the values to it (as it is done in the `main.cpp`) when its found?

I'm quite sure one can use a for loop but how should I be doing it? Any help will be appreciated.

### main.cpp

```
int main()
{
    Expression expr("x + y + sqrt 25 - 3");

    expr.instantiateVariable('x',5);//Set x = 5
    expr.instantiateVariable('y',3);//Set y = 3

    /*
    The output of the following statement should be:

    Answer: 10
    */
    cout<<"Answer: "<<expr.evaluate()<<endl;
}
```

and in my header folder I have the following:

### Expression.h

```
class Expression
{
    public:
        Expression(string expr);
        ~Expression();
        void instantiateVariable(char name, int value);
        int evaluate();
};
```

Comment: Parse the expression with a stack or [something like this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm)

Answer (score 2):

I would go for a naive [Shunthing-yard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm). The principle is easy:

1. Reach each operand and put them on a queue
2. Every time you encounter an operator put it on a stack
3. If the operator on top of the stack has a higher precedence pop it and add it to the queue (it needs to be calculated first)
4. Continue until the end of the expression and then pop everything to the queue

supporting parenthesis is also easy with this method.

Some parsing is obviously required (a tokenization to be precise) but this is going to be pretty straightforward.